# Configuring the EurekaInstanceConfigBean for AWS in Spring-Cloud-Netflix (Brixton.RELEASE)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

With the release of the Brixton Release Train, I have noticed that there has been an update to the `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` interface, specifically, the default constructor has been made `private`, and a new constructor has been introduced that takes in an instance of `org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils`.

With the Angel Release Train, many examples online ([cloud.spring.io included](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html)) showed that this bean was configured similar to the following when working within AWS:

```
@Bean
@Profile("!default")
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig() {
    EurekaInstanceConfigBean b = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean();
    AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
    b.setDataCenterInfo(info);
    return b;
}
```

I understand that I can probably get this to work by creating an instance of `InetUtils` and providing that to the constructor, but I am more curious about the **best practices** for creating this `@Bean` and configuring it to work with AWS.

Is the intent to just create the instance of `InetUtils`, or utilize AutoConfiguration, or a specific `@Enable*` annotation, or even just set the field in a `@PostConstruct` method?  Something else perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InetUtils` is a bean, simply inject it.

```
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils) {
    EurekaInstanceConfigBean b = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
    //...
    return b;
}
```

The bean comes from AutoConfiguration, specifically, the [`org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.UtilAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/commons/util/UtilAutoConfiguration.java) class, which is a part of spring-cloud-commons jar.